# Cant acces array[0] of rows returned by exceljs

Tags: arrays, typescript, javascript-objects, map-function, exceljs

this is my first question and I hope someone can help me, I need to convert an excel to json to upload the data to a DB with Angular and exceljs, I've been trying a lot of things but I could not find a solution.

All the excel values are loaded in an Array of Arrays called rows (or Object, because typeOf(rows) returns Object), but i cant map this Array anyway, i've tried the next:

```
wb.xlsx.load(buffer).then(workbook => {

    let sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
      sheet.eachRow((row) => {
          rows.push(row.values);
      })
})
```

//console.log(rows) returns an array full of data, but `rows[0]` is undefined, see below:

```
Array []
​
0: Array [ <1 empty slot>, "some text" ] // have to delete this row
​
1: Array(19) [ <1 empty slot>, "code", "name", … ] // have to delete this row
​
2: Array(19) [ <1 empty slot>, "XXXXXX", "CourseName", … ]
​
3: Array(19) [ <1 empty slot>, "XXXXXX", "AnotherCourseName", … ]
```

in the code my next step is mapping the array, but its impossible to access with [0] or with `Object.keys(rows)[0]`, Array.map is below:

```
rows.map((row:Excel.Row): Course | undefined => {
    console.log('hi'); //don't logs nothig here<--------------------------------
    try {
      let course =  new Course({
        code: this.getCellValue(row,1),
        name: this.getCellValue(row, 2),
        start: this.getCellValue(row, 3),
        end: this.getCellValue(row, 4),
        preStart: this.getCellValue(row, 5),
        preEnd: this.getCellValue(row, 6),
        endDate: this.getCellValue(row, 7),
        place: this.getCellValue(row, 8)
```

Have more code below but i need to map the array, sure I'm missing something basic, thank you if you are reading this!

Comment: Right before your `rows.map(` does `console.log(rows)` log anything?

Comment: How do you "delete" those rows? Actual `delete` properly removes the 0th index from `keys()`: `rows=[1,2,3,4];console.log(Object.keys(rows));delete rows[0];console.log(Object.keys(rows));`. However setting an element to `undefined` does not: `rows=[1,2,3,4];console.log(Object.keys(rows));rows[0]=undefined;console.log(Object.keys(rows));`. Honestly I don't like any of the two, personally I would `shift()` from the beginning of an array, `pop()` from the end, and probably would `splice()` from the middle, if knowing that there are elements removed is not needed in the future.

Comment: Sorry for wasting ur time and thanks! I solved it and the problem was the async, had to then after the map function, and i filtered the rows by undefined to delete that two, ill leave the code here if someone has the same problem, thank u!

Answer (score 0):

```
loadFile(e:Event|any) {
this.file = e.target.files[0];}

  convert = async (docType:string) => {
let reader = new FileReader();
let rows:Array<any> = [];

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
reader.onload = () => {

  const buffer:any = reader.result;
  const wb = new Excel.Workbook();

  wb.xlsx.load(buffer)
  .then(workbook => {

    let sheet = workbook.worksheets[0];
    sheet.eachRow((row,i) => { rows[i] = (row.values) })

    return rows;})
    .then(
      rows => {
        this.data = this.processData(rows,docType);
      })
}
  }



processData = (rows:any,docType:string) => {
    if (docType =='cursos') {
      try {
      return this.data = rows.map((row:Excel.Row | any,index:number): Course | undefined => {
                  if (index === 1 || index === 3){
                      return;
                  }
          return new Course({
            code: row[1],
            name: row[2],
            ...
          })
        }).filter(this.isUndefined);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return
      };
    }
```